# Blazor - clear all select options without refetching data

Tags: blazor

Blazor .NET 6.0, I have the basic select element:

```
<select id="ProductItems" @onchange="ProductSelections" multiple size="10">
    @if (items!= null)
    {
        @foreach (var item in items)
        {
            <option value="@item.Id">@item.Description</option>
        }
    }
</select>
```

I have been asked to provide a button that will clear the list of any selected options. I do not want to have a code heavy solution, and I also do not want to code any js.

One solution that does work is if I refetch the data when the button is clicked:

```
List<MyItems> items = new List<MyItems>();
....
private async void ButtonClearClick() 
{
    items = new List<MyItems>();  // clear variable.
    items = await GetAllItems();  // web api call to reload variable.
    StateHasChanged();
}
```

This does cause the select to briefly collapse and reload, but at least all options are cleared.
I next turned to refactoring that solution to avoid the db call, and thought that using a temp variable would accomplish the same thing:

```
private void ButtonClearClick2() 
{
    List <MyItems> temp = new List<MyItems>();
    items.ForEach(i => temp.Add(i)); // copy into temp.

    items = new List<MyItems>(); // clear variable.
    temp.ForEach(i => items.Add(i)); // copy back into variable.
    StateHasChanged();
}
```

However this does NOT work, options are still selected. There is also no collapse/reload effect, which tells me that nothing was reloaded. Can someone explain what is wrong with the second attempt? What am I missing?

Comment: Are you binding the select to anything? Can you share the entire select along with the attributes you're using.

Comment: @RBee The select is not bound to anything, I have updated the element with the info that I had left out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind the select to a `T[]` where `T` is the type of your `MyItem.Id` property. Then when you clear that array you will also be clearing the selected options.

```
<select @bind="firstIds" multiple size="10">
    @if (options!= null)
    {
        @foreach (var item in options)
        {
            <option value="@item.Id">@item.Description</option>
        }
    }
</select>
<button @onclick="ClearFirstSelection">Clear First Selection</button>
@code{
    int[] firstIds = new int[0];
    private void ClearFirstSelection()
    {
        firstIds = new int[0];
    }
}
```

Here's a snippet that demonstrates this.

[Telerik snippet](https://blazorrepl.telerik.com/cRkNYPPr53sCVDj844)

Comment: Thank you, your solution does work for clearing the options. However, it has introduced a new challenge. I was doing processing in method ProductSelections called by *onchange. The *bind in your solution does not allow me to use *onchange anymore. So I must find a way to call ProductSelections from the change event that is being called, once I identify the latter.

Comment: Found a solution to my latter problem: There is a bind:after available with .net 7, so I upgraded my project from 6.0 to 7.0, and can use that to call the method originally called by onchange. Thanks again for your solution.

Comment: If you were using .Net 7+ then you could add a `@bind:after` for that. You can also use property with a getter and setter where you call the `ProductSelections` method in the setter. https://blazorrepl.telerik.com/GxYDkbcY08VrGWwQ51

Comment: Ah ok thought you weren't able to upgrade for whatever reason :) .